# Tibco FT issue because of heartbeat

Tags: tibco, tibco-rv

I have 2 instance of my Java application (A & B) running on same machine, where B is blocked for `activate()` callback.

This is how I register my callback:

```
new TibrvFtMember(this.tibrvQueue,
   this.orv,
   this.transport,
   MessagingProps.TIBCO_GROUP_FT, // Group name
   wt,            // Weight
   1,             // Active members
   2.0,             // Heartbeat (secs.)
   0.0,           // Prep. (secs.)
   2.5,             // Activation (secs.)
   null);
```

I sending heartbeat every 100 millisecond to ensure that my application is on time.

```
msg.add("Data", ++seq + ":" + MessagingProps.TIBCO_SUBJECT_FT);
                msg.setSendSubject(MessagingProps.TIBCO_SUBJECT_FT);
                transport.send(msg)
```

For some reason (ex., GC / garbage collection) if my active application "A" delays in sending heartbeat, immediately my passive application  "B" gets activated while "A" is still active, where deactivate is not invoked on "A".  And soon after application "A" sending a heartbeat,  deactivate is invoked on application "B". This give an erroneous behavior for a few seconds since both the applications are active at the same time.

The mentioned is happens at random time and not predictable. Our application cannot publish duplicate messages at same time, so this creates a huge impact.

Kindly help me to how can I overcome this issue.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am able to control it my increasing the latency of heartbeat from 100 millisecond to 800 milli, just before 1 sec. Understood that it may be caused due to busy RVD.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: thanx anna.,  After thorough investigation found that multiple threads blocked heartbeat from getting on to RVD. We have cleared the blocking . Yourkit helped a lot to trace out the issue. Its not tibco FT issue.